# Invalid Region error only on one device

Tags: ios, maps, mapkit, cllocationmanager, region

I'm trying to show a map in my application, it works on my simulator and on my ipod touch 4g.

But I always get an error on my iPhone and I don't know why this happens.
Maybe you can explain me why it fails. 
The error is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region `<center:nan, nan span:nan, nan>`'

I already searched for solutions on google and stackoverflow but it seems that nobody has this problem.

Thats my code:

```
//setup mapview
mapView.delegate = self;
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

//set up core location
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;

//Set up zoom location
CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
zoomLocation.latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
zoomLocation.longitude= locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;

debug(@"Location: %f und %f",locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude,locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);

//zoom to location
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];                
[mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

As I said, it works on iPod and simulator, but not on iPhone.

Hope you can help me

**SOLUTION:**

I used the locationManager too early, so the app crashed. Now I used it this way:

```
      - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//setup mapview
mapView.delegate = self;
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

//set up core location
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    }

   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
//Set up zoom location
CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
zoomLocation.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
zoomLocation.longitude= newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
[mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];

debug(@"Location: %f und %f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude);


    }
```

Don't know if this way is 100% correct, but it works.

Comment: What version iPhone are you using?  Does it have a retina display?

Comment: What is the METERS_PER_MILE constant? And why are you multiplying it by 0.5?

Comment: it's an iphone 4s with iOS 6, so yes it have a retina display. The Meters per mile is defined as: #define METERS_PER_MILE 1609.344

Comment: Where are you calling startUpdatingLocation?  You shouldn't try to use locationManager.location right after creating it.

Comment: that was the problem! thank you :) I just had to place the locationManager stuff in another position. Will edit the solution in my question. Thanks!

Comment: I would consider answering this question yourself and accept it so it doesn't affect your accept rating. Sounds like you figured it out.